# does hibernate+sqlite+tomcat work?

Tags: hibernate, sqlite, tomcat

I have an urgent problem:

I have a jar which contains a hibernate+sqlite project (It does simple operations on a db).

I have included this jar in a web project and created a web service which creates an instance of a class from the jar.

The web service is on a Tomcat 6 server.

But when I call the WS's method, it stops execution when trying to create the object. And the crazy thing is that it doesn's show anythig in the console. The jar has logging and it works when called from a regular java project.

The jar and WS work fine when are used separately. It may be a simple solution but since the logging doesn't work I can't find out what's wrong?

Any solution would be great (logging, classpath?).

Comment: Welcome to SO , use some line breaks ( double enter )